# Raspberry Pi python kayboard background listener

Tags: python, keyboard, raspberry-pi, keypress, raspberry-pi2

I am currently trying to create a python script that will listen for a keypress, specifically numpad along with the Numlock, / , * ect. The script will eventually be added to a shared memory script I wrote and will be run as a daemon.

I need this listener to be independent of of any open window or focus. A key logger if you will, so no matter what i am doing if i press a key it will be picked up by my script.

The trouble i am having at the moment is poor documentation of most things i find and python is not my main language. I have found pygame, termios and some others but i cant seem to find a straight forward solution.

So basically my question is, how can i capture a keypress regardless of the current active window? 
Library recomendations, code or anything would be a massive help as i have been stuck on this for quite some time.

Thank you.

Comment: You would probably have to read from the appropriate device under `/dev/input`. Here is an [example in C++](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys)

Comment: there was `pyKeylogger` or `pyHook` to do something like this. Besides there is program [AutoKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoKey) for Linux which listen all keypress and it is made in Python - maybe you could see something interesting in source code.